# Laravel mail sending returns error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to use the laravel 5.3 mailable for email verification, but it's not working and returns me this error -

```
FatalThrowableError in RegisterController.php line 84:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Mail' not found
```

The top of the RegisterController.php looks like -

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

```
use App\Mail\VerifyEmail;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
```

VerifyEmail is my mailable class generated using `make:mail`.

Line 82-84 of RegisterController.php -

```
$email = new VerifyEmail($verification_code);
Mail::to($data['email'])
    ->send($email);
```

The full stack trace is pasted here http://pastebin.com/r9sQpPdy.

Comment: in your terminal (cmd on windows) , try `composer dumpautoload -o`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use the `Mail` facade in class that's in another namespace, without importing (`use`) it.

You either do:

```
\Mail::to($data['email'])
    ->send($email);
```

OR you should `use` it:

```
use App\Mail\VerifyEmail;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Mail;

class RegisterController extends Controller
```